# Chess view and javafx

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, abstract

I need some advices about how to build code correctly.
I creating a chess viewer using `javafx`.

1) As a new one I don't exactly know what is the best way to make correct hierarchy.
I think to create `abstract` `class` `Figure`  and the problem is it seems I need overide own behavior.

I tried extends Node but it seems wrong. 
What is correct way to extends to make custom element in `javafx`?

Maybe you know good link anout creating custom element (not necessary chess) where described this process.

2) I looked at both (browser chess/desktop programms) and one thing about I'm thinking is when you grab & hold chess piece icon and dragging around the board the image icon is moving after your cursor. So in javafx it can be done with `MouseEvent` that's I understand.

But the question is how to redrawing it? Calculating coordinats?

3) About board. I think it is good way to make some class `Cell` based on `Rectangle` ovveriding behavior and class `Field` which include array of `Cell`(s)?

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow.  For pointers, take a look at some basic board game rendering in JavaFX, a [tic-tac-toe](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5115901) implementation and [another tic-tac-toe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/paper-doll.htm) implementation.  Chess is similar, just more complicated :-)  For the move logic, you could implement [drag-and-drop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/drag-drop.htm#top) like this [paper doll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/paper-doll.htm).

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks, those examples are good.